# Reloading custom tool from svg markup string

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the Markup Core extension and have created a custom tool with Edit Mode etc. The tool seems to be working fine on first adding to the canvas, dragging, resizing and on clicking save, I can see my new DotMarkup in the markups array.

However, when calling generateData and saving an svg string, an attempting to load the data onto a new layer using loadMarkups(svg, layerName) the custom markup is shown on screen but is unclickable, the markup is not visible in the markups arrays (on the editor, or in the svg markups array).

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently been looking into this as well, and unfortunately it turns out that exporting and re-importing custom markups is not yet supported by the `MarkupsCore` extension. If you look at the [extension code](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Markup/Markup.js) and search for `createMarkupFromSVG`, you'll notice towards the end of the function that it's just a long `switch` with the built-in markup types. So, while your custom SVG *is* loaded, it's not considered a "markup SVG". To work around this issue you would probably have to parse the SVG string yourself and set the internal state of of the extension (such as `this.markups`) manually.

Comment: With that said, I will reach out to the engineering team, and see if this is something that could be added in one of the future releases.

Comment: Thanks Petr, appreciate the answer... I thought as much. We're creating a custom dotting tool which adds a dot and text, with a set colour. I save the SVG string and can reload it but we really needed it to be reloaded and it to be editable. 

For a current work around I'm just having to grab the data, delete and recreate, it means we can't drag the existing shapes around, but if we click Edit it disappears and re-appears wherever they next click.

Would be a great addition to be able to load custom types! Thanks again!